# JavaScript Code Explanation For: (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement)

Tags: javascript, html, object, nodes

I have made a JavaScript tab view of a simple HTML page. 
I've added onClick functions for header tags using JavaScript via nodes. 
The onClick function performs a function called **showTab** passing on **this** as a parameter. 
I understand that **this** is **[object window]**.

The header tag onClick functions are set as shown below:

```
node.onclick = function() { showTab(this); };
```

The showTab function is as follows:

```
function showTab(e) 
{ 
    var node = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement); 
    alert(node.innerHTML); 
}
```

Everything works fine, when i click on one of the headers, an alert appears with its innerHTML.

However, I did use a little help from Google to achieve this. And I would like some help understanding exactly what this line means:

```
var node = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
```

I did my own research and saw it can be considered as the equivalent as sender in C#.

But I would like to know thoroughly how it works and what it is referring to and how it knows which node is calling the showTab function as there are 3 header tags that perform the same function, all without id's.

Comment: > *Everything works fine*. You tried Firefox yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the joys of dealing with Events and browser.

The Trident Engine (Internet explorer and others based on that engine) deals with events differently than most (all?) of the other browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="test_button">Click me</button>

<script>
// UGLY, UGLY, UGLY... don't really use this
var button = document.getElementById("test_button");
if (window.attachEvent) {
    button.attachEvent("onclick", showTab);
} else {
    button.addEventListener("click", showTab);
}

function showTab(e) 
{

    // Most browsers pass the event as 'e'
    // Microsoft puts the event in window.event
    // Either way, event will now point to the object we want.
    var event = e || window.event;


    // Once again, the different browsers handle the `target` property differently.
    // Target should now point to the right event.
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    alert(target.innerHTML); 
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. I'm having to pass on 'this' to the showTab so I can identify which header tag was clicked. Is there another way to implement this without sending 'this' and not having to worry about which browser I am using. If I try passing on the node (header tag) it keeps thinking I'm clicking the last header tag in the node list.

Comment: @HH -- Without seeing  the code that you use, I can a very good guess at what you are doing.     Sounds like you need to use a `closure`. [This example covers your use case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff696765.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var node = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
```

is equivalent to this logic:

```
var node;
if (e && e.target) {
    node = e.target;
} else if (window.event && window.event.srcElement) {
    node = window.event.srcElement;
} else {
    node = undefined;
}
```

The purpose of this code is to handle the fact rhat older versions of IE don't pass the event structure to an event handler.  Instead, it is stored in a global variable `window.event` and the event target is also stored in a difference property of the event.

It is a bit more common (and I think more readable) to do something like this:

```
function showTab(e) { 
    // get the event data structure into e
    e = e || window.event;

    // get the source of the event
    var node = e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert(node.innerHTML); 
}
```

In reality, any decent size project should use a library function for abstracting the differences in event handlers so that this browser-specific code only has to be one place in the project or use a pre-built library like jQuery for this type of thing.  Here's a cross-browser event handler:

```
// refined add event cross browser
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    if (typeof elem === "string") {
        elem = document.getElementById(elem);
    }

    function listenHandler(e) {
        var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        if (ret === false) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    function attachHandler() {
        // older versions of IE
        // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
        // make sure the event is passed to the fn also so that works the same too
        // normalize the target of the event
        window.event.target = window.event.srcElement;
        var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);   
        if (ret === false) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's getting the dom element which was clicked, either e.target for standards compliant browsers or window.event.srcElement (could be e.srcElement instead for newer IE)

see: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html